# How to run a specific goal on a multi-module project?

Tags: maven-3

I have multiple modules and I would like to have `clean install` goals run against a set of modules and followed by that I would like to have `clean tomcat7:deploy` run against a specific module. This has to be done in a incremental manner.

I know this can be run in a two command line statements, like this:

```
mvn -pl moduleA,moduleB,moduleC clean install
mvn -pl moduleD clean tomcat7:deploy
```

Is it possible to consolidate these above two statements into one?

Or, in my case, `moduleD` is dependent on `moduleA`, `moduleB` and `moduleC`,
so I would rather use the `-am` flag (also make):

```
mvn -am -pl moduleD clean tomcat7:deploy
```

but `tomcat7:deploy` is not applicable to the dependent modules A, B, and C.

How can I accomplish this?